# How to force gRPC to use TLS1.2 (not TLS1.3)

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

It is my understanding that gRPC uses TLS1.**3** by default. Is there a way to force it use TLS1.**2**? I know it is possible to do with Microsoft's implementation of gRPC for .Net Core. But I need to do it with Google's implementation for .Net Framework.

I've tried finding searching for any info but it seems that most people are concerned with forcing the latest TLS. I need the opposite: enforcing use of older TLS.

Comment: There is a 32 bit register in Windows where each bit contains a different SSL/TTLS version like SSL, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1,2, TLS 1.3.  The client sets which versions it wants to use.  So if only TLS 1.2 is set than the other versions will be disabled.  It is a static register and to set TLS 1.2 you use : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: If there's a way to configure this in Grpc.Core (the gRPC C# implementation based on gRPC C-core native library - which is the one you want according to your original post), it's going to be configured in the same fashion as in gRPC C++ / C core.  Have you investigated existing channel arguments (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/impl/grpc_types.h) and or env variables https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md?